# ReactNativeVisionCamera with ObjectDetection: distance / too far away

Tags: react-native, expo, tensorflow-lite, react-native-vision-camera

I would like to create a feature in my app that is like a banking app, where the camera detects an object, but it is too far away, and it suggests to the user to get closer.  That's all that is needed right now - determine if object is too far away.

I am using Expo (React Native), with react-native-vision-camera.  I am not sure any of the [Frame Processors](https://react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/frame-processors) suggested work out of the box.  I thought I could try to use either [vision-camera-image-labeler](https://github.com/mrousavy/vision-camera-image-labeler?tab=readme-ov-file) or [vision-camera-realtime-object-detection](https://github.com/jaroslawkrol/vision-camera-realtime-object-detection) but the second requires my own TFLite model.

What's the best way to go about this?